# Less mixin with optional parameters

Tags: css, parameters, less, mixins

I have a `Less` mixin defined as:

```
.fontStyle(@family, @size, @weight: normal, @style: normal, @color: #ffffff, @letter-spacing: normal) {
  font-family: @family;
  font-size: @size;
  color: @color;
  font-weight: @weight;
  font-style: @style;
 letter-spacing: @letter-spacing;
}
```

How can I define usage like:

```
.fontStyle('NimbusSansNovCon-Reg', 12px, , , , 0.1em);
```

I.E. use the defaults for `@weight`, `@style`, `@color`

Answer (score 37, accepted):

To supply a parameter that far down the string of arguments, you have to also supply the expected variable it is to define. So this:

```
.fontStyle('NimbusSansNovCon-Reg', 12px, @letter-spacing: 0.1em);
```

Produces this (note how `color`, `font-weight`, and `font-style` used the defaults):

```
font-family: 'NimbusSansNovCon-Reg';
font-size: 12px;
color: #ffffff;
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
letter-spacing: 0.1em;
```

Answer (score 2):

See the documentation

http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-parametric-feature-mixins-with-multiple-parameters

Note: you should get in the habit of using semicolons to separate parameters since some css values can contain commas.